# OPENSHIFT - 'wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'

Tags: openshift

I am trying to start a new `python3.3` app on Openshift. Due to the changes they made a couple of weeks ago I am having trouble getting the new app started. I copied a known working app into a new Openshift app. I am now getting this error:

`Target WSGI script '/var/lib/openshift/<masked>/app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.`

My `wsgi.py` code is the same in both working and non working apps

```
import os
from myapp import main_production_no_pserve

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
    app = main_production_no_pserve(global_config=None)

    from waitress import serve
    print("Starting Waitress Server on http://{0}:{1}".format(ip, port))
    serve(app, host=ip, port=port, threads=50)
```

The working app was created before the mid March Openshift change.  Something is different now that the exact same code does not work.

It seems openshift is looking for an `application` function entry point within the `wsgi.py`.  In the old method of the working app, the `wsgi.py` is actually executed (not looking for the `application` function.  For kicks, I did this based off of the default `wsgi.py` when new openshift app was created.

```
import os
from myapp import main_production_no_pserve

def application(environ, start_response):

    ip   = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
    app = main_production_no_pserve(global_config=None)

    from waitress import serve
    print("Starting Waitress Server on http://{0}:{1}".format(ip, port))
    serve(app, host=ip, port=port, threads=50)

    return
```

With that change I get the dreaded `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use` and a `rhc app-force-stop` does nothing.

I am at a loss why one app works and another does not.  I would appreciate some help. :)

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, with the same error message in the application logs.

Comment: I find that the app.py entry point can be more reliable. You can search my name on here for example code on Github.